# What is the difference between Hyperlink control and link control in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

What is the difference between Hyperlink control and link control ASP.NET?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The purpose of both controls is same. But there is one major difference between these two, i.e. HTML Hyperlink control is an HTML control, whenever it is clicked the page navigates to the target page. ASP.NET Link Button control is a server control, whenever the user clicks on it, the request is redirected back to the server and in its response the page is navigated to the target page.

Answer (score 8):

The HyperLink control immediately navigates to the target URL when the user clicks on the control. The form is not posted to the server.

The LinkButton control first posts the form to the server, then navigates to the URL. If you need to do any server-side processing before going to the target URL, use a LinkButton.

Answer (score 5):

The `<asp:Hyperlink>` control is a Web server control, while the `<a>` link is the bare-bones HTML control.

Like all WebControls, the former provides a full featured programming event model, while the latter allows you to render an HTML anchor. You could add the `runat="server"` attribute to the link control to enable it to be accessed in server-side code. This attribute would however be required for the `Hyperlink` control (because it is a ASP.NET object that renders as an `<a>` hyperlink in HTML.